# Running parallel python scripts from bash file

Tags: python, bash

Given the following bash script

```
batch.sh

python train.py --arg1
python train.py --arg2
python train.py --arg3
python train.py --arg4
```

Is there an easy way such that all scripts will be called parallelly? 
I.e not waiting for the first call to `train.py` finish before calling the second?

Comment: Add "&" after each call to a python program, and the shell will move right on to the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put `&` behind your command

```
python train.py --arg1 &
python train.py --arg2 &
python train.py --arg3 &
python train.py --arg4 &
```

it put your jobs in the background
for more informations visit this wiki [wiki](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Putting_jobs_in_background)

edit:
for work in batches there exist multiple ways

one example could be to count the running background jobs, i.e:

```
sleep 1001 &
sleep 1002 &
sleep 1003 &

jobs # for listing all running background jobs
>[1]   running     sleep 1001 &
>[2]-  running     sleep 1002 &
>[3]+  running     sleep 1003 &
```

now you can count them with `wc` like

```
# count lines of output
jobs | wc -l 
> 3
```

now all together in a loop:

```
while true
do

  # check if 3 background jobs are running
  while [ $(jobs | wc -l) -ne 3 ]
  do 
    sleep 10 & 
  done
  sleep 1 # check every second if 3 jobs are running

done
```

Comment: Is there a way to work in batches? meaning that in each moment there are only 3 parallel jobs?

Comment: @DsCpp that's the kind of thing that should be included in the question! (You can still edit it to add that, because it makes a big difference.)

Answer (score 2):

You can add an "&" ("ampersand") after each call to a program, and the shell will move right on to the next without waiting for it to finish. So, to run all your programs in parallel you'd do it like this:

```
python train.py --arg1 &
python train.py --arg2 &
python train.py --arg3 &
python train.py --arg4 &
...
```

But now you say you want no more than three to run in parallel. That's a bit trickier: If you pause after every third command, some may take a lot longer than others and you can end up with too many long ones running.

Instead, launch three sets of sequential commands that will run in parallel:

```
( python train.py --arg1  
  python train.py --arg2 
  python train.py --arg3
  python train.py --arg4
  python train.py --arg5
  ... ) &

( python train.py --arg11 
  python train.py --arg12 
  python train.py --arg13 
  ... ) &

( python train.py --arg21 
  python train.py --arg22 
  python train.py --arg23 
  ... ) &
```

Each parenthesized group will execute its contents one at a time, but the three groups will run in parallel. Of course if one group finishes early, it will *not* start executing a command from another group; after that point you'll only have two train runs in progress. So, make groups that should require roughly the same total time.

This has nothing to do with Python, by the way. It is basic shell syntax, and you can use it with any other command you would call from the shell.

Comment: Nice workaround! thanks a lot, I'll do that:) As most runs should take pretty much the same time, it may seem like a hack at first, but it's easy and perfectly suits the scenario!

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like:

```sh
parallel python train.py ::: --arg1 --arg2 --arg3 --arg4
```

It will run one job per CPU thread. When one job finishes, another will be started.

Answer (score -2):

you can also add semicolon to have a one liner command.

```
python train.py --arg1 & ; python train.py --arg2 & ; python train.py --arg3 & ; python train.py --arg4 &
```